# Как лучше спроектировать базу данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, innodb

**Сфера тематики:** cs
**Задача:** Иметь список всех никнеймов и ip-адресов игрока
**Вопрос:** Какое отношение связей выбрать?
**Наиболее частые запросы:** update and insert
**Редкие запросы:** select

**1.**
Если иметь 1 таблицу получим много повторяющих данных, например:
**Имеем таблицу:** id, steamid, ip, name, created_at, updated_at
**Мысли в слух:** Если имя у игрока сменится, то мы снова добавим строчку с теме же данными steamid и ip, получается дублирование данных. Забиваем диск избыточной информацией, но вставка и чтение данных будет проще

**2.**
Если иметь 3 таблицы

1. Таблица users: id, steamid, joins, created_at
2. Таблица names: id, user_id, name, usages, created_at, updated_at
3. Таблица ip: id, user_id, ip, usages, created_at, updated_at

**Мысли в слух:** меньше избыточности, но несколько запросов на вставку данных, соответственно немного муторнее вставлять обновлять данные ну и получать. В промежуточной таблицы names и ip будут дублироваться данные для других игроков, так-как игрок может иметь несколько имен и имя может быть у нескольких игроков

**3.**
Если иметь 5 таблиц, что бы создать связь многие ко многим

1. Таблица users: id, steamid, joins, created_at, updated_at
2. Таблица names: id, user_id, name, created_at
3. Таблица ip: id, user_id, ip, created_at
4. Таблица lnk_users_names: id, user_id, name_id, created_at
5. Таблица lnk_users_ip: id, user_id, ip_id, created_at

**Мысли в слух:** Практически полностью убираем избыточность, но дико усложняем запросы на вставку и обновление данных, ведь что бы вставить данные во все 5 таблиц понадобиться несколько запросов на вставку а так же возможно селектов, что бы получить id и вставить ее потом в промежуточные таблицы

Отсюда и возникает вопрос, какую связь выбирать и почему, одно дело если мы убираем избыточность, другое дело если мы добавляем больше гемора для работы со вставкой

Comment: Выглядит так, что уникальный только steamid, тогда все сводится к одной таблице и всё. Если это не так, то я вообще не представляю себе другой признак по которому можно было бы понять, что это один и тот же игрок.

Comment: @Talleyran да, уникальный тут steamid, но как я уже говорил, один steamid может иметь кучу никнеймов, если использовать одну таблицу у нас получится кучу дублирующих данных: типа steam1 nik1, steam1 nik2 и так далее

Comment: У меня несколько мыслей по поводу. 1. Можно часть данных хранить в одной колонке в виде json/xml. То есть все имена пользователя будут в виде массива. 2. При использовании нескольких таблиц - one-to-many и many-to-many - работу с ними может сильно облегчить ORM. Зависит от используемого языка программирования. 3. В некоторых СУБД есть так называемые _исторические_ таблицы: history или temporal table (не temporary!). Насколько я знаю, в MySql таковых нет. Но, вроде, есть в MariaDB под названием System-Versioned Tables.

Comment: Из описанных вариантов однозначно следует выбрать тот, который соответствует нормальным формам, т.е. вариант 3. Несколько запросов на вставку в рамках транзакции ненамного медленнее одного в денормализованную таблицу. А селекты при правильной индексации и очевидном предположении, что будет выбираться единственная запись - тоже быстро.